# How to dynamically re-render a view when continuously changing its state through an algorithm?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a View displaying the values of an array marked as a `@State` property.
When e.g. I have a Button to sort the array how can I achieve that SwiftUI updates the screen for each step in the sorting algorithm that mutates the values of the array?

In this test example I made a button sorting the array with bubble sort:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var array = [5,3,6,9,1,2,4,13,3,4,16]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            ForEach(0..<array.count, id: \.self) { i in
                Text("\(array[i])").padding()
            }
        }
        
        Button("Sort") {
            var j = array.count
            while j >= 1 {
                for i in 1..<j {
                    if array[i] < array[i-1] {
                        let temp = array[i-1]
                        array[i-1] = array[i]
                        array[i] = temp
                    }
                }
                sleep(1) // to compensate for the short runtime in this example 
                j -= 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why is SwiftUI re-rendering the view only once although the `@State` property gets mutated with each sorting step?
Is it possible to visualize each step on-screen somehow and to not only see the end result of the algorithm?

I want this behavior to visualize the backtracking steps when running something similar to a sudoku solver. Thanks in advance for any help!

PS: I'm quite new to Swift/SwiftUI and this is also my first question on Stack Overflow. Apologies if I wasn't specific enough or missed something obvious!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `sleep`, you'd block the main thread and prevent UI updates. Instead, you could using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` to run each successive step of the sorting:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var array = [5,3,6,9,1,2,4,13,3,4,16]
    @State private var currentElement = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            ForEach(array, id: \.self) { i in
                Text("\(i)").padding()
            }
        }
        
        Button("Sort") {
            currentElement = array.count
            withAnimation {
                runSortStep()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func runSortStep() {
        for i in 1..<currentElement {
            if array[i] < array[i-1] {
                let temp = array[i-1]
                array[i-1] = array[i]
                array[i] = temp
            }
        }
        currentElement -= 1
        if currentElement >= 1 {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                withAnimation {
                    runSortStep()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've also changed your `ForEach` so that each element is identified by the array value and not the index -- otherwise, you won't see the animations.

Comment: Actually I added the `sleep(1)` part just in order to manually extend the runtime in this example. Thx for letting me know that this would be an issue but in fact I didn't use any artificial delays in my real project because the runtime there is substantially longer. I want to see the current state of the array in my view as if I would be printing the array to the console after each step and for me it seems like the problem lies with the view updating just once in the end instead of after each mutation - please tell me if this is definitely not the issue here.

Comment: If you want to see the state update, you have to finish the current run loop. If your code just takes a long time to finish but all takes place in one run loop, you’re probably better off doing it on a different thread and sending updates to the main thread when you have them.

Comment: I'm sorry that I apparently constructed such a bad example. Should I update the example to be more in line with my actual project and remove the `sleep` part? I'm not sure because if I replace the example it would obviously make your suggestions about the former `sleep` part pointless?

Comment: If you edit your question to reflect your real question I suppose I can just delete my answer. Does my above comment make sense, though?

Comment: Could you explain why it is that I "have to finish the current run loop" to see the state update? I would also prefer not having to get too deep into managing threads because as I said I'm very much a beginner with Swift and SwiftUI.

Comment: Why does the run loop have to finish? Because that's when SwiftUI updates the screen. If it has continually executing code, it won't ever have a chance to actually write the updates to the screen. Since everything is on the main thread, there's no way for SwiftUI to cut in and render the update, since it's *already* on the main thread. If you truly have a long-running task, you are not going to have any option other than running it on a different queue/thread. Not having any info on what you're doing, it's tough to say how complicated that will be, but Swift/Foundation makes it pretty easy.

Comment: With your last comment it now makes completely sense to me why it wasn't working. It actually seems pretty obvious when I think about it now. Thank you very much! Can I somehow make it clear to others that this comment of yours was the actual explanation I was looking for?

Comment: When I’m back at my computer I’ll add it to the answer.